# Is there a way to retrieve values from Canvas context?

Tags: javascript, html

It was previously explained here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript/21015393#21015393) how to compute a text string length in pixels, with a solid reference to http://jsfiddle.net/eNzjZ/34/.

In the jsFiddle example a `font` parameter string is passed to `getTextWidth`. This parameter string includes the font size in pixels. The returned result *in pixels* is logged to the console.

Assuming that I want to convert the result into another units (em, pt…), I need retrieve from the parameter string the original font size in pixels in order to make a conversion. Is there a way to do it *from within* `getTextWidth` using a Canvas property ?

In other words, how can I *straightforwardly* retrieve or extract the font size from the context.font property?

EDITING : MORE CLUES

`typeof (context.font)` returnq a string including the correct font-size value. The topic of parsing a CSS string in shorthand format has been dealt with here ([How to parse CSS font shorthand format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618676/how-to-parse-css-font-shorthand-format)). But I am so far unable to extract a specific value from the string without implementing a parse algorithm of my own… There must be a fast lane.

Comment: JS is always returning measurements in px. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Justinas  -- Take a look at the jsFiddle example: you will see that the font parameter gets stored in the context.font property, and then that the metrics method is applied to the context. What I am aiming at is specifically retrieving the font-size of the font parameter from within the getTextWidth function, i.e. from the context. Please note the said font-size (12pt)  is part of the second parameter string in the example call — console.log(…)

Comment: Beware all UAs don't agree on what should return `context.font`. FF does return the authored value (e.g with `"12pt sans-serif"` it will return `"12pt sans-serif"`) while Chrome does return a partially computed value (with same example it will return `"16px sans-serif"`). The serialization part of CSS specs is somehow unclear on that point, but you would be better using directly the `font` variable instead of `context.font` anyway if you want to get back `"12pt"`.

Comment: (Ps: I don't know of a good way to get this `"12pt"` from the shorthand btw. I think your question would win by asking only this, since at the end, canvas part is unrelated to your root problem).

Comment: @Kaiido — Please refer to my editing of the post.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, can you enlighten me in how I misread this edit? It still not clear if you want the `"12pt"` value or the `"16px"` one. For the later, it's easy and has already been answered in the Q/A you linked to. For the former, that would make a good question, if there weren't the unrelated canvas noise.

Comment: @Kaiido — I will get back to you later, for I am to go out. Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: @Kaiido — Now, the problem is not about retrieving the _unit_ of the font size, but any part of the string — which could be fontStyle, fontVariant. I have sorted it out. Please my own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ere: [How to parse CSS font shorthand format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618676/how-to-parse-css-font-shorthand-format) **thirtydot** cleared the way.

Actually, I have not found a direct access to context.font, but **thirtydot**'s algorithm does the trick simply and efficiently.

```
// (…)
context.font = myOwnCSSString;
metrics = context.measureText (texte);

var $test = $('<span />');
$test.css('font', context.font);

console.log ($test.css('fontWeight'));
console.log($test.css('fontStyle'));
console.log($test.css('fontVariant'));
console.log($test.css('fontSize'));
// etc…
```

The second argument to .css() is a classic css shorthand string. Parsing returns the expected result.

Please note that with both Firefox and Chrome the result is returned in *pixels* and might be converted into points if need be..

Comment: Seriously? So you just wanted what was already in the Q/A you linked to? Why shouldn't this be made a duplicate? Why don't you use directly `myOwnCSSString` instead of going through `context.font`?

Comment: @Kaiido. _Seriously_ I do not use the string directly because my question is only part of a more complex algorithm: it is another function that initializes the said string whose outcome I cannot forecast. Actually it took me some time to understand that `context.font` returns a shorthand CSS string and to find the right link to it: [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font). Thus this could help other users.