# How to get a style property from <style> tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a method in JavaScript:- `element.style.anyProperty;` but that returns a css value from `style attribute` but does not grab it from `<style>` tag. How can I get any property from tag not attribute in JavaScript? For example:-

```
<style>
    div{background:red;}
</style>
```

Now how can I get this background property or current background of any element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [myDiv.style.display returns blank when set in master stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748813/mydiv-style-display-returns-blank-when-set-in-master-stylesheet)

Comment: [Relevant MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984885/can-i-programmatically-traverse-a-css-stylesheet The solution lead me to write quite a neat API to get style information directly from the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets), that return you a list of [CSSStyleSheet objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet).

Then you can use these objects to get all the CSS rules contained in each of the style tags.

For your style example, you should get:

```
var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;
var first_rule = styleSheetList[0].cssRules[0];
console.log( first_rule.selectorText);  //should print "div"
console.log( first_rule.style.background);  //should print "red"
```

Note that:

1. You can also change these objects at runtime to change your page styles
2. You only get the rules for inline style, not for that linked from external resources
3. All css property are transformed in CamelCase, e.g. background-color is represented as backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

This code checks the style sheet rules and if it finds white then sets it to red.

```
var ssObj;
if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules) {
  ssObj = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
}
if (document.styleSheets[0].rules) {
  ssObj = document.styleSheets[0].rules;
}
for (var i = 0; i < ssObj.length; i++) {
  if (ssObj[i].style.color == 'white') {
    ssObj[i].style.setProperty('color', 'red', null);
  }
}
```

As you can see there are two ways of getting the rules depending on browsers, but once you have that then the rest is straight forward.

Answer (score -3):

Something like this:

CSS markup:

```
<style>
  #myID { background:red; }
</style>
```

Javascript markup:

```
document.getElementById("myID");
```