# What regex shall I use to fetch the content of css classes and store them?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have created a textbox to copy content from the PDF and accept the content in rich text format.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Theme.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <textarea id="ta" onpaste="functionItalic(event)" class="foostyle2"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 20px;">
        <span id="1">Karan's</span>
     </span>
    <span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px; font-style: italic;">test</span>
</div>
<script>
function functionItalic(pasteEvent)
{
var textareacont = (pasteEvent.originalEvent || pasteEvent).clipboardData.getData("text/html");
console.log(textareacont);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I printed the content on console(the content was  **For smoke-protected assembly seating, the common**), I found that the content in the PDF contains css classes and html tags like this

**Note**: this code was obtained on execution of `console.log(textareacont);`
    
    
    
    
    
    For smoke-protected assembly seating, the common

```
CSS Tweaking.html (line 19)

<html>
<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style>
<!--
br
{
mso-data-placement:same-cell;
}
table
{
mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\, ";
}
tr
{
mso-height-source:auto;
mso-ruby-visibility:none;
}
td
{
border:.5pt solid windowtext;
}
.NormalTable{cellspacing:0;cellpadding:10;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-layout-alt:fixed;border:none; mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .75pt;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; mso-border-insideh:.75pt solid windowtext;mso-border-insidev:.75pt solid windowtext}
.fontstyle0
{
    font-family:Times-Roman;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
.fontstyle1
{
    font-size:12pt;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
.fontstyle2
{
    font-family:Times-Italic;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
-->
</style></head><body>
<!--StartFragment-->
<span class="fontstyle0">For </span><span class="fontstyle2">smoke-protected assembly seating</span><span class="fontstyle0">, the </span><span class="fontstyle2">common</span> 
<br style=" font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; ">
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is that I want to get the properties of css classes with name .fontstyle1,.fontstyle2,.fontstyle3 in string format, someone said that this can be achieved through **RegEx** can anybody tell me what will be the RegEx that I need to use so as to store .fontstyle classes in string. I have tried a few but they have'nt work. The **newlines,carriage returns and tab feeds** are part of the string only that are appearing in the classes.

If somebody knows an another way of storing the .fontstyle classes content in string.Please help I don't know much about regex.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. You can use this regex

```
/\.fontstyle\d+\s*\{[\w\s-:;,()]*\}/g
```

I'm not sure if i'm giving too much help but since its already coded...

```
    // The regular expression
    var regularExp = /\.fontstyle\d+\s*\{[\w\s-:;,()]*\}/g;
    var match;
    // .fontstyle will be stored in fontstyle_list[]
    var fontstyle_list = [];

    // Finds all match
    while (match = regularExp.exec(/*The css file (converted to string) should go here*/)) {
        // Adds every match into fontstyle_list
        fontstyle_list.push(match[0]);
    }

    // Iterate through every element in fontstyle_list
    for (var i in fontstyle_list){
        // prints out each .fontstyle{}
        document.write(fontstyle_list[i] + "<br />"); // document.write() is unsafe and should only be used for testing

        // add your codes here

    }
```

#### 2. Alternatively

You can parse the css into an object before using substring to retrieve each element that starts with '.fontstyle'

1. Parse the css into an object. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865690/6943913
2. Iterate through all elements of the object in step 1
3. For each element in step 2, perform `<eachElement>.substring(0, 10) === ".fontstyle"`
4. For each operation that returned true in step 3, copy out the element into another list

*Disclaimer: the steps above is just to illustrate the program logic, some adjustments might need to be made to fit the actual scenario