# Change tag type based on CSS settings using PHP

Tags: html, css, dom, dom-traversal

I need to read data from an HTML file. The HTML file includes a  element with CSS rules. Based on the CSS rules I need to change `<span>` into `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`.

Unfortunately I can't base it on classname or ID because these will change.

Is that possible with DOM traversal?

**I want this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.exampple1{font-weight:700}
.exampple2{font-style:italic}
.exampple3{text-decoration:underline}
.exampple4{font-weight:700;font-style:italic;text-decoration:underline}
.exampple5{font-weight:700;font-style:italic}
.exampple6{font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline}
.exampple7{font-style:italic;text-decoration:underline}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><span class="exampple1">bold text</span></p>
<p><span class="exampple2">italic text</span></p>
<p><span class="exampple3">underline text</span></p>
<p><span class="exampple4">bold, italic and underline</span></p>
<p><span class="exampple5">bold and italic</span></p>
<p><span class="exampple6">bold and underline</span></p>
<p><span class="exampple7">italic and underline</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**To become this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p><span class="exampple1"><b>bold text</b></span></p>
<p><span class="exampple2"><i>italic text</i></span></p>
<p><span class="exampple3"><u>underline text</u></span></p>
<p><span class="exampple4"><b><i><u>bold, italic and underline</u></i></b></span></p>
<p><span class="exampple5"><b><i>bold and italic</i></b></span></p>
<p><span class="exampple6"><b><u>bold and underline</u></b></span></p>
<p><span class="exampple7"><i><u>italic and underline</u></i></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you're looking for some server-side PHP code to compute the effective style and then covert this information into plain HTML tags? Would a style attribute on the paragraph or span not work?

Comment: No, unfortunately style would not work because the style settings for each class can contain multiple settings. Also I don't want any inline style in the HTML. But if that is possible for only these style settings maby I can do a stringreplace. Please let me know if it is possible to add the style atributes. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

DOM traversal is something that is done in JS, so I presume such a solution will work for you?

In JS you can parse the contents of your `<style>` element [with the browser's own CSSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865690/552067). Then you can use the selector from each of those parsed CSS rules to query elements and set CSS properties on those elements with `element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can only use PHP (sorry for my mistake tagging DOM traversal, I thought that what it's called in PHP as well).