# Separate text by space or character and include the character

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I want to slip a text by spaces and special character but I want to keep those character. The text I want to separate is in the CSS format. Take the following example:

```
.box {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

I already have that in an array format by line like this

```
[ " .box { " ]
[ " background: red; " ]
[ " } " ]
[ " color: white; " ]
```

And I want to split every string by space and these characters ':' and ';'

so I'll en up with something like this:

```
[".box"] ["{"]
["background"] [":"] ["red"] [";"]
["color"] [":"] ["white"] [";"]
["}"]
```

I want to take in mind the syntax, here are some possible scenarios:

```
background: red;          -> ["background"] [":"] ["red"] [";"]
background      : red ;   -> ["background"] [":"] ["red"] [";"]
backg    round : red ;    -> ["backg"] ["round"] [":"] ["red"] [";"]
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

About the duplicate question, I'm looking into the other post answer and it might help in my specific case, nevertheless the problem discussed might be in different other context other than parsing CSS. Please consider that, and thank you for the reference.

Comment: though you're not spliting by spaces (you are just trimming them) and you are not spliting by `;` neither as that will result in additional empty strings in all the arrays.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir If I just do it by spaces this `background: red; ` will become this `["background:"] ["red;"]` and not this ["background"] [":"] ["red"] [";"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSS in JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326494/parsing-css-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a loop over the array elements and calling `.match()` with this regex: [**`/(\[\.\#\]?\[a-z\]+\[\s?>+~\s?\[a-z\]+\]?)|(\[{:};\])|(\[a-z0-9\]+)/gi`**](https://regex101.com/r/doIJVo/1) to get all the separate elements:

```
var results = [];
arr.forEach(function(a) {
  a[0].match(/([\.\#]?[a-z]+[\s?>+~\s?[a-z]+]?)|([{:};])|([a-z0-9]+)/gi).forEach(function(m) {
    results.push(m);
  });
});
```

You can test the [**Regex** here](https://regex101.com/r/doIJVo/1) to see that it matches all CSS selectors.

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [
  [" .box { "],
  [" background: red; "],
  [" } "],
  [" color: white; "]
];

var results = [];
arr.forEach(function(a) {
  a[0].match(/([\.\#]?[a-z]+[\s?>+~\s?[a-z]+]?)|([{:};])|([a-z0-9]+)/gi).forEach(function(m) {
    results.push(m);
  });
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: what if no spaces in the property rules?

Comment: This does not work, for example on this `[" background: red; "]` the result should be ["background"] [":"] ["red"] [";"] and instead I get  `[ 'background:', 'red;' ]`

Comment: @OmarAguinaga Take a look at my Edit

Comment: @Downvoter can you please leave a useful comment?! Why would we downvote a correct answer?!

Comment: Keep in mind the css rules can be more complicated than the examples given. `#-~+_:` can appear in there. oh and Unicode.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes I know, I updated the regex and it works perfectly with all type of selectors.

Comment: @OmarAguinaga So does this help you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have to say I liked @GabyakaG.Petrioli answer as well, maybe better because is more readable, but since yours solves the specific problem I'll give this to you.

Comment: For regex and css you will really need to see the full specs and create a huge one to handle all cases. Check https://regex101.com/r/doIJVo/2 for failed ones.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes of course, I know that, there are many other selectors and properties that we need to check for. Even your solution, won't work with all kind of selectors.

Comment: this is totally of topic now but do you have any resources to learn Regex? @chsdk

Comment: @OmarAguinaga First you need to get the concepts of Regular expressions, flags, matches, ... you can take a look at [**Mastering Regular Expressions**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) there are 3 editions of it, then you will be better learning with practice you can check either [**regexr.com**](https://regexr.com/) or [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/). This was really helpful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

```js
var originalText = `.box {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}`;

var parsed = originalText
              .split(/( |:|;|\n)/g) // split and maintain by using capturing group
              .filter(p=>p.trim()); // keep only non whitespace elements

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Even with this solution there are a lot of selectors that won't be matched. Check this [**Fiddle example** for more details](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/Lywqjzs5/) about how it fails.

Comment: Don't get me wrong here, but all I want to show is that it's a little bit inappropriate to handle all these selectors, we should check for more complex situations.

Comment: @chsdk fair enough. I am not trying to pick on you solution, i just have a general aversion to using regex for parsing whole specs.