# How do I parse CSS to prefix CSS selectors

Tags: css, node.js, parsing

I have the following `my-file.css`:

```
.a [data-smth] { ... }
.b .c.d { ... }
.e { ... }
#f { ... }
```

and I want to do something like the following (pseudocode) in Node.js:

```
let css = readFile('my-file.css')
let prefixedCss = prefixClasses(css, 'prfx-')
writeFile(prefixedCss, 'my-prefixed-file.css')
```

to end up with `my-prefixed-file.css`:

```
.prfx-a [data-smth] { ... }
.prfx-b .prfx-c.prfx-d { ... }
.prfx-e { ... }
#f { ... }
```

I have found these npm modules:

https://github.com/vic/prefix-css (hasn't been updated in years and has issues)

https://pegjs.org/ (requires lots of low-level AST configuration)

But I was wondering whether there are better/safer solutions that have already been tested/become standard practice ?

**NOTE:** *The above file contents was just an example. I'm looking for a way to achieve this for files whose content is completely unknown to me. So I'm looking for a "universal" solution.*

Any help would be most welcome & thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: It looks like a simple regular expression replacement would take care of that, is there any specific roadblock you're running into?

Comment: Not sure a simple RegEx on a CSS string is a safe solution as I'm looking for a universal solution (see edited OP). I'm worried that something like `replace .XXX with .prfx-XXX` could affect a `.XXX` occurrence in the file that is not necessarily a class CSS selector but maybe an [attribute] value or the value of the `content` CSS property or other.

Comment: A context selector would not suffice? Like `.prfx .a { ... }`? And what would you expect happens to compound selectors like `#d .a[href⁼https] > .icon-link { ... }`?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it has to be a prefix for every classname used in every CSS selector in the file

Comment: compound selectors like `#d .a[href⁼https] > .icon-link { ... }` will also have to be prefixed see my updated OP

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/marceloucker/postcss-prefixer?

Comment: this looks promising @connexo thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check https://github.com/marceloucker/postcss-prefixer#postcss-prefixer.

> ## postcss-prefixer
>
> [image: Build Status] [image: dependencies Status] [image: devDependencies Status]
>   [image: License: MIT]
>
> PostCSS plugin to add a prefix to all css selectors classes and ids.
>
> ### Usage
>
> #### With [PostCSS cli](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli):
>
> Install `postcss-cli` and `postcss-prefixer` on your project directory:
>
> ```
> npm install postcss-cli postcss-prefixer --save-dev
> ```
>
> and at your package.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>       "postcss": "postcss input.css -u postcss-prefixer -o output.css"
> }
> ```
>
> #### Others
>
> ```
> postcss([ require('postcss-prefixer')({ /* options */ }) ])
> ```
>
> ### Options
>
> #### prefix
>
> ```
> Type: `string`<br>
> Default: none
> ```
>
> String to be used as prefix
>
> #### ignore
>
> ```
> Type: `array`<br>
> Default: `[]`
> ```
>
> Array of selectors to be ignored by the plugin, accepts string and regex.
>
> ### Example
>
> Example of usage with results generated by the plugin.
>
> #### Code
>
> ```
> const postcss = require('postcss');
> const prefixer = require('postcss-prefixer');
> const input = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file.css',  'utf-8');
> const output = postcss([
>   prefixer({
>         prefix: 'prefix-'
>         ignore: [ /selector-/, '.ignore', '#ignore' ]
>     })
> ]).process(input);
> ```
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> #selector-one .example {
>   /* content */
> }
> .selector-two .example2 {
>   /* content */
> }
> #ignore .ignore {
>   /* content */
> }
> #ignore .other {
>   /* content */
> }
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> ```
> #selector-one .prefix-example {
>   /* content */
> }
> .selector-two .prefix-example2 {
>   /* content */
> }
> #ignore .ignore {
>   /* content */
> }
> #ignore .prefix-other {
>   /* content */
> }
> ```
>
> ### Credits
>
> Plugin based on [postcss-class-prefix](https://github.com/thompsongl/postcss-class-prefix) create by [thompsongl](https://github.com/thompsongl).

Comment: this is also pretty helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865690/2272048